# Появление кнопки в Unity3D, зависящие от количества символов в InputField. C#

Tags: c#, unity3d

Помогите пожалуйста с кодом. Создаю свою игру в **Unity 3D**. Хочу создать **InputField** в который пользователь будет вводить какие то данные. И хочу реализовать в скрипте метод чтобы подсчитывалось количество символов в **InputField**(*без пробела*) и если это значение больше минимального заданного (*допустим 2*) появлялась кнопка далее. Помогите пожалуйста, а то уже с этим долго мучаюсь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(input.text.Replace(" ", "").Length > 2) {
    buttonNext.SetActive(true);
}
```